# adding pipeline between page numbers in pagination control

Tags: jquery, css

I have an pagination control on search results page of Moss 2007 by default. I have an requirement to separate each page number by pipeline symbol.

```
Eg: <Prev> |1|2|3|4|5|<Next>
```

Mark up is something like this:

```
<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
&nbsp;4&nbsp;
<a>5</a>
```

Where in page number 4 is the current one. I tried with a:after and a:before.

Output was something like this:

```
<Prev> |1|2|3 4 5|<Next> (Note that, there is no separator between 3,4,5)
```

Any useful suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It has nothing but this markup:<div class="srch-Page srch-Page-bg">
<a id="SRP_Prev" title="Previous page">&lt;Prev</a> &nbsp;
<a id="SRP_P1" title="Page 1">1</a> &nbsp;
<a id="SRP_P2" title="Page 2">2</a>
 &nbsp;3 &nbsp;
<a id="SRP_P4" title="Page 4">4</a>  &nbsp;
<a id="SRP_P5" title="Page 5">5</a>  &nbsp;
<a id="SRP_P6" title="Page 6">6</a> &nbsp;
<a id="SRP_P7" title="Page 7">7</a>  &nbsp;
<a id="SRP_Next" title="Next page">Next&gt;</a> &nbsp;
</div>

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the html of the pagination control do something like this (replace `&nbsp;`):

```
<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
<span>4</span>
<a>5</a>
<a>6</a>

a:after, span:after {content:" |"}
a:last-child:after {content:""}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cAwMg/5/

(note this is css3 - older browsers won't support this - if you want to make it compatible with older browsers use classes (.previous, .next, .selected etc.))

Answer (score 0):

**At last, here goes the solution ... **

```
function replaceAll(OriginalString, SearchString, ReplaceString) {
                while (OriginalString.indexOf(SearchString) != -1) {
                    OriginalString = OriginalString.replace(SearchString, ReplaceString);
                }
                return OriginalString;
            }
function PipeLineSeparator()
{
            var sPaginationString = jQuery(".yourDiv").html();
            sPaginationString = replaceAll(sPaginationString, '&nbsp;', '<span"> | </span>');
            sPaginationString = sPaginationString.substring(0, sPaginationString.lastIndexOf("|"));
            jQuery(".yourDiv").html(sPaginationString);            
}
```